# Software for an internal Knowledge Base, with support for existing documents

Tags: cms, wiki, knowledge-base

At my company we need to implement a knowledge base for our new support team.

Currently we have a NAS full of Word (doc and docx), OpenOffice (odt) and Pdf documents, with all the information.

**We are looking for some kind of user editable website (a wiki, maybe?), with full text support that can search the website content AND all the NAS documents**. Also, we want that users can continue modifying existing NAS documents in an agile way (they have direct access to the NAS from Windows Explorer as a shared folder).

This, more or less, can be made with a "simple" [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) installation (using the [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch) plugin and an ElasticSearch server), but there are a couple of problems:

- All the documents should be uploaded to MediaWiki to be indexed.
- Every time a user made a modification to a document (docx, doc, odt or pdf), a new version should be uploaded to MediaWiki.

Do you know any web software, ready to be locally installed, that supports content creation and indexing and searching in a shared directory?

Answer (score 1):

I really much recommend a Wiki. What seems most important to me is to not duplicate content.

Probably you could gradually move content from the file-based-documents into the Wiki?

We use [FosWiki](http://foswiki.org/) in my shop. It's simple (and thus very powerful). Most importantly you can easily create pages which include other pages. We use this extensively to have full documents, like a user manual, an installation manual etc.. where some chapters are the same.

Comment: Does FosWiki address the issues with indexing documents from a shared folder automatically?

Comment: @holroy i honestly dont know

Comment: Thats why i hesitated to post as an answer, but it was too long for a comment

Answer (score -1):

With your requirements, I would suggest you to get [ProProfs Knowledgebase](http://www.proprofs.com/knowledgebase/). Simply because content creation is as simple as picking up a pen and all the offline documents you have can be uploaded instantly on the cloud.

You can also set privacy options to keep your sensitive information safe. With the privacy options only the relevant teams/members would be able to see the information.

Hope it helps.